# OSX Mavericks Trash Question

Tags: macos

why does an item remain in trash after I drag it out onto the desktop. It does indeed go to the desktop, but it still remains in the trash (OSX Mavericks). lion,etc once dragged out, it immediately left the trash.

Comment: I have just tested this and on my Macbook Air (running OSX Mavericks 10.9.2), items dragged out of Trash immediately disappear from Trash.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case. Have you ctrl + click on the item and "Put Back"? Do you still get the same results? Do you know if its a locked file and what are your computer specs?

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure what your setup is, so my answer is pure guessing.

So it happened before when I was using ParagonNTFS to delete some files from NTFS filesystem. What you need to do is boot into your Windows (BootCamp), use its built-in partition repair tool to repair the partition. Then uninstall ParagonNTFS because it will damage your NTFS partition!

Answer (score 0):

Would need to confirm this with your specific setup, but I suspect this is due to multiple drives or partitions. Whenever you move a file to a different partition it triggers a copy, not a move.

Each drive or partition has its own trash.

If you have an item on one drive, then move it to the trash, and then move it from the trash to a second drive, you're really triggering a copy of the file to the new drive.

You can see the individual trash folders at the root of each partition, called .Trashes, inside which will be a folder for each user (UID) on the system.

I just tested this theory on my Mavericks (10.9.2) system, and this is the current behaviour.